# Do I need a GPU even to deploy a deep learning model?

Tags: deployment, deep-learning, model, gpu, artificial-intelligence

I know I do need a GPU to train a model but even after the model is trained  do I need a GPU to deploy the same trained model?
For example I have a model for a car with auto-pilot to predict and take a decision... Do I need a GPU for the prediction too..

Specially in case of reinforcement learning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking you usually don't need a GPU for training either depending on the platform, it would just be much slower than if you utilized he GPU rather than the CPU.

For deploying the model you do not need a GPU. Most models are simply an organized list of weights which are used by the model to operate on its inputs. Since this usually isn't particularly computationally expensive, except for very large models, a GPU isn't necessary for deployment either, but may provide some performance benefit for lager models.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help :D

Comment: @joshmeranda You mentioned GPUs are required for 'large models'. Would you call 'RoBERTA' from Hugging face library a large model and would it require GPU for deployment ?

Comment: @rishikeshfulari TBH I don't have too much experience with gauging model sizes, or any experience with RoBERTA, so I can't give you an informed response and don't want to accidentally mislead you.  The best guidance I can give you is to play around with the library, and if you are encountering performance issues, you might need a GPU. Although, I wouldn't imagine that this is very common.